# Error jQuery! Loop function of animate ' Slide and click to active'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I get code of jQuery http://codepen.io/lolliuym/pen/MewJeX. 
Example, I writed as http://www.cantorfineart.com/.

```
function callBack() {
    $('.active-pistol').addClass('activeOpacity');
    $('.active-bub').removeClass('activeOpacity')
    $('.bub-jumpo').animate({
      'left': '-50%'
    }, 1000).removeClass('active');
    $('.fullwidth').animate({
      'left': '0'
    }, 1000).addClass('active');
    $('.bub-jumpo').animate({
      'left': '100%'
    }, 1, callBack ).delay(2000);     
}

$('.active-pistol').click(slidePistol);
$('.active-palm').click(slidePalm);
$('.active-bub').click(slideBub);
callBack();
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: this basic code iquery is my error that is not right as http://www.cantorfineart.com/